# How to paste a shape after selection

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

Just wondering how I can paste an object after I have selected it in Excel 2003:

```
sheet1.shapes("MyShape").select

With Selection
```

basically jsut wondering how to duplicate a shape object, or any object really. Eventually I am looking to use code to copy a shape object like above from Excel, and paste it into an access form automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("MyShape").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
```

You could of course copy it to another sheet.